# Can CMake find_library search other "drives"?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

Context:

- Windows 10
- CMake 3.13

I have a `Findxxxx.cmake` script working like a charm for a while.
I wanted to change the directory in which my dependency was stored so I copied it to a mounted network share (i.e. under a different "letter"). I updated the PATH accordingly but bad luck, my dependency wasn't found anymore.

I reverted back the PATH to point to the original dependency location *(which I never deleted)* and it started finding the library again.

Since I simply copied the dependency directory to another location, I have a bad feeling that the fact CMake can't find the library at the new location is because it's somewhat located on different drive with a different "letter"...

*I took a look at the [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/find_library.html) documentation but I found nothing mentioning some restrictions about drive letters.*

What do you guys think about that ?

EDIT: Here is my Findxxxx.cmake. It's to search for `libsodium`.

```
find_path (
    LIBSODIUM_INCLUDE_DIRS
    NAMES sodium.h
    HINTS ${PC_LIBSODIUM_INCLUDE_HINTS}
)

find_library (
    LIBSODIUM_LIBRARIES
    NAMES sodium libsodium
    HINTS ${PC_LIBSODIUM_LIBRARY_HINTS}
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

find_package_handle_standard_args(
    LIBSODIUM
    REQUIRED_VARS LIBSODIUM_LIBRARIES LIBSODIUM_INCLUDE_DIRS
)
mark_as_advanced(
    LIBSODIUM_FOUND
    LIBSODIUM_LIBRARIES LIBSODIUM_INCLUDE_DIRS
)
```

EDIT 2: Just tried through PowerShell instead of good old CMD and it seems to work in both cases.

Comment: How do you search for the library? Please show us the file, or at least try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Have you tried using the share's name instead of the drive letter in either your path variable or the excplicit search directive in your cmakelist? i.e.: `\\share\build\cmake_libraries`

Comment: Current problem description is quite *vague*. Instead of detailed description of what works and what doesn't it is better to show **exact** setting of `PC_LIBSODIUM_INCLUDE_HINTS` variable used in your script and **exact** location of the library file. Knowing [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) you use 
would be useful too.